# File won't be moved to another location using Ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload a file and move it to a folder upon button click using Ajax and PHP. It does return true for success but the file uploaded is not moved to the destination folder. Here is a snippet of the Ajax upload

```
btnsubmit   = $(".submit");

//the function for handling button click
     btnsubmit.click(function(){
            var file_data = $('#uploaded_img').prop('files')[0];   
            var form_data = new FormData();                  
            form_data.append('file', file_data);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'upload_img_custom.php',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: form_data,                         
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(php_script_response){
                    alert(php_script_response);
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is the PHP file

```
<?php
    $upload_directory = "../uploads/Customized/";
    if (isset($_FILES['uploaded_img']))
    {
        $uploadedFileName=$_FILES['uploaded_img']['name'];
        $targetPath=time().$uploadedFileName; //time is concatenated to make filenames unique
        if($uploadedFileName != '')
        {
            $targetPath=time().$uploadedFileName;
            move_uploaded_file($uploadedFileName, $upload_directory."".$targetPath);
        }
    }
    header('Location: customize.php?upload=success');
?>
```

HTML (Only the important part)

```
<form method=POST id=customize-form action ="" enctype=multipart/form-data>
     <div id=step3 class='options step'>
        <section class=section-title>Image</section>
        <div class=image-display><img id=image-disp src="" width=99 style="text-align:center" /></div> //div for displaying uploaded image
        <section style="margin-bottom:10px">
            <label class="paragraph-font2 full-width">Choose what you want on the top of your cake:</label>
        </section>
        <section style="margin-bottom:15px">
            <input class="paragraph-font2 full-width" type=file name=uploaded_img id=uploaded_img accept="image/*">
        </section>
    </div>
    <button type=submit class='btn btn-info action submit'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart'></span> Add to cart</button>
</form>
```

I've check the limit for uploads. The file I'm trying to upload is only 170KB. The limit I've set is 20M.
The 'Customized' folder is inside another folder for this project in xampp htdocs.

Comment: Did you check the request parameters ? All the values are being sent to the server.. and also the permissions of the folder where you are supposed to put your new file?

Comment: @Vincent I have not. How do I do that?

Comment: You can check from your browsers console to see if all the form values are being sent across to the server-side, or just do a `print_r($_FILES); exit();` in your PHP code, see if there are any error messages.

Comment: I do not think that it's a good idea to use `header()` in the AJAX answer, because you JS code is waiting for some string response. Further, the `""` in `move_uploaded_file()` might have been intended to be a `'/'`.

Comment: @BurninLeo I will try your suggestion. Btw I'm trying to concatenate the destination and folder on that one that's why I used "".

Comment: @Vincent It prints the following:
array([file] => Array 
([name] => picture.png
[type] => image/png
[tmp_name] => C:\xampp\tmp\php73FF.tmp
[error] => 0
size => 174917
)
)

From the looks of it, there doesn't seem to be any errors.

Comment: @BurninLeo Unfortunately, after removing the header, it still does not move the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you named your files variable "file" (in JS), you should use "file" in the PHP code, too:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file']))
```

and

```
$uploadedFileName=$_FILES['file']['name'];
```

Or you change the JS part:

```
form_data.append('uploaded_img', file_data);
```

And you need to move the temporary file name, not the original file name:

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $upload_directory . $targetPath);
```

Comment: Thank you! Goodness I've wasted so much time just because of that. It was because I copied that syntax from copy function!